# Error in creating android bouncing ball program

Tags: android, eclipse

can you help what possible error in this code? i need to create bouncing ball application for my project. i need to correct all the error. thanks for helping me.

```
package com.awai.bouncingballdemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
public class GraphThing extends SurfaceView implements
SurfaceHolder.Callback, OnTouchListener { //error is here

protected TutorialThread _thread;
protected int _x=100;
protected int _y=100;

public GraphThing(Context context) { super(context); getHolder().addCallback(this);//error
_thread = new TutorialThread(getHolder(), this); //error
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE); Paint paint = new Paint(); paint.setColor(Color.RED); paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL); paint.setAntiAlias(true); //error
canvas.drawCircle(_x, _y, 80, paint); //error
}

public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) { //error
return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) { //error
_x = (int) event.getX();
_y = (int) event.getY();
return true;
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int //error
width, int height) {
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) { //error
_thread.setRunning(true);
_thread.start();
}
```

here another code from this application

```
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) { //error
boolean retry = true;
_thread.setRunning(false);
while (retry) {
try {
_thread.join(); retry = false;
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
// we will try it again and again...
}
}
}

class TutorialThread extends Thread {
private SurfaceHolder _surfaceHolder; //error
private GraphThing _panel;
private boolean _run = false;

public TutorialThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, GraphThing panel) { //error
_surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder; //error
_panel = panel;
}

public void setRunning(boolean run) {
_run = run;
}

@Override
public void run() { Canvas c;  while (_run) { //error
c = null; try {
c = _surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null); //error
synchronized (_surfaceHolder) { //error
_panel.onDraw(c);
}
} finally {

if (c != null) {
_surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c); //error
}
}
}
}
}
```

the last part of my code...

```
public class OpenGLGraphics extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  GraphThing gt = new GraphThing(this); setContentView(gt); //error
}
}
```

Comment: i just wanna know the requirment : how u want to bound a ball? on touch od boundry in scene ?

Comment: @Monica the ball bouncing itself...

Comment: By bouncing ball, you mean a game like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dxball ? Where you have a stick at the bottom and bricks at the screen and you use the ball which bounces of the stick to destroy the bricks?

Comment: ok i think any game engine will do that but above logic will make it complex

Comment: @Monica check your email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Hi kindly find the attached source code ..
Issue was u hv declared two public class in one activity only..
```

[Code.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cesri73yjjy2v73/BouncingBall.zip)

Answer (score 0):

I have written this code in Processing and you can create it in android.. [visualize here](http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/67284)

```
    /*
a bouncing ball
*/

float ballX = 100;
float ballY = 0;
float h = 50;

//create a variable for speed
float speedY = 2;

void setup() {
  size(400,400);
  smooth();
  noStroke();

  // change the mode we draw circles so they are
  // aligned in the top left
  ellipseMode(CORNER);

}

void draw() {
  //clear the background and set the fill colour
  background(0);
  fill(255);

  //draw the circle in it's current position
  ellipse(ballX, ballY, h,h);

  //add a little gravity to the speed
  speedY = speedY + 0.5; 

  //add speed to the ball's
  ballY = ballY + speedY;


  if (ballY > height - h) {
    // set the position to be on the floor
    ballY = height - h;
    // and make the y speed 90% of what it was,
    // but in the opposite direction
    speedY = speedY * -0.9;

    //switch the direction
    //speedY = speedY;
  }
  else if (ballY <= 0) {
    // if the ball hits the top,
    // make it bounce off
    speedY = -speedY;
  }


}
```